# Why do Javascript classes reference the same constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reflection, constructor

I'm trying to reflect a javascript object on a class but for some reason, it seems the constructor for all javascript classes point to the same reference object in memory. This means that i cannot reflect 2 different objects on 2 separate javascript classes because the first one just gets overwritten by the second.

```
require('reflect-metadata');

class Class1 {}

class Class2 {}

class Sub1 {}

class Sub2 {}

Reflect.defineMetadata("METADATA", Sub1, Class1.constructor);
Reflect.defineMetadata("METADATA", Sub2, Class2.constructor);

console.log(Class1.constructor === Class2.constructor); // true
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('METADATA', Class1.constructor)) // [Function: Sub2]

const cls1 = new Class1();
const cls2 = new Class2();

Reflect.defineMetadata("METADATA", Sub1, cls1.constructor);
Reflect.defineMetadata("METADATA", Sub2, cls2.constructor);

console.log(cls1.constructor === cls2.constructor); // false
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('METADATA', cls1.constructor)) // [Function: Sub1]
```

I'm trying to understand why non-instance JavaScript objects seem to point to the same location in memory and reference the same base constructor

Comment: `Class1.constructor === Class2.constructor`; Try using `Class1` and `Class2` in `Reflect.defineMetadata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand why non-instance JavaScript objects seem to point to the same location in memory and reference the same base constructor

The class name IS the constructor itself.  So, if you want a unique reference to each class's constructor, then use the class name itself.

On the other hand, `Class1` is an already constructed Function object and thus `Class1.constructor` is the constructor for that Function object as is `Class2.constructor` so thus they each point to the same Function object constructor.  That's why:

```
Class1.constructor === Class2.constructor
Class1.constructor === Function.prototype.constructor
function f() {}
Class1.constructor === f.constructor
```

If you want the constructor for `Class1`, you can reference it with either `Class1` or with `Class1.prototype.constructor`, not with `Class1.constructor`.

So, you will find that:

```
Class1 !== Class2
Class1 === Class1.prototype.constructor
Class1.prototype.constructor !== Class2.prototype.constructor
```

> Why do Javascript classes reference the same constructor?

Because `Class1.constructor` is the constructor for the already constructed `Class1` Function object, not the constructor for your class.  The constructor for your class would be `Class1` or `Class1.prototype.constructor`.

Comment: Great explanation